# Extracting N number of matches from a text string in R?

Tags: r, text, text-mining, stringr

I am using stringr in R, and I have a string of text that lists titles of news articles. I want to extract these titles, but only the first N-number of titles that appear. In my example string of text, I have three article titles, but I only want to extract the first two.

How can I tell str_extract to only collect the first 2 titles? Thank you.

Here is my current code with the example texts.

```
library(stringr)
```

Here is the example text.

```
texting <- ("Time: Friday, September 14, 2018 4:34:00 PM EDT\r\nJob Number: 73591483\r\nDocuments (100)\r\n 1. U.S. Stocks Rebound Slightly After Tech-Driven Slump\r\n   Client/Matter: -None-\r\n   Search Terms: trade war or US-China trade or china tariff and not dealbook\r\n   Search Type: Terms and Connectors\r\n   Narrowed by:\r\n             Content Type                         Narrowed by\r\n             News                                 Sources: The New York Times; Content Type: News;\r\n                                                  Timeline: Jan 01, 2018 to Dec 31, 2018\r\n 2. Shifting Strategy on Tariffs\r\n   Client/Matter: -None-\r\n   Search Terms: trade war or US-China trade or china tariff and not dealbook\r\n 100. Example")
```

```
titles.1 <- str_extract_all(texting, "\\d+\\.\\s.+")
titles.1
```

The current code brings back all three matches in the string:

```
[[1]]

[1] "1. U.S. Stocks Rebound Slightly After Tech-Driven Slump"

[2] "2. Shifting Strategy on Tariffs"                        

[3] "100. Example"
```

I only want it to collect the first two matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the option `simplify = TRUE` to get a vector as result, rather than a list. Then, just pick the first N elements from the vector

```
titles.1 <- str_extract_all(texting, "\\d+\\.\\s.+", simplify = TRUE)[1:2]
```